# What control flow to implement when I want the user to not name his/her characters chosen with a same name?

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

I am quite new to coding, so simple tasks seems like the mount Everest. I have created a Switch statement for a player to choose 3 out of 4 characters to play with. I' d like him/her to name their characters uniquely.
I tried by adding a "parameter [String]" to the method and inside it, adding each characters name, using a "for Loop" to check if a character has already be named this way.
The thing is that I keep looping and can' t sort out how to name each character uniquely. 
If someone has any clue, thanks to answer.

```
func makeTheTeam(listOfName: [String]) {

    var listOfName = listOfName

    // Presents all the fighter available
    gameAction.charactersPresentation()

    while listOfFighters.count < 3 {

        print("\nInput a number associated to select a fighter:")
        if let userChoice = readLine() {

            print("Name your fighter:")
            if let nameChoice = readLine() {

            switch userChoice {
            case "1":
                listOfFighters.append(Warrior(fighterName: "\(nameChoice)"))
            case "2":
                listOfFighters.append(Wizard(fighterName: "\(nameChoice)"))
            case "3":
                listOfFighters.append(Colossus(fighterName: "\(nameChoice)"))
            case "4":
                listOfFighters.append(Dwarf(fighterName: "\(nameChoice)"))
            default:
                print("You have not chosen three characters to enter the ring!! \n\nEnter a number associated to a fighter...")
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting rid of the "unique" names issue, you could:

**1-** Get the benefit of using *Sets*, by converting `listOfName` to a *set* and check the counts:

```
if Set(listOfName).count == listOfName.count {
    // unique names, we are good to go
} else {
    // similar names... 
}
```

OR

**2-** if your desired behavior is to check the array sequentially after adding each element, you could use `contains`. As an example of the basic usage for it:

```
var names = [String]()
var inputName = "Jack"

// will append "Jack"
if names.contains(inputName) {
    // name is already exist
} else {
    names.append(inputName)
}

inputName = "Smith"

// will append "Smith"
if names.contains(inputName) {
    // name is already exist
} else {
    names.append(inputName)
}

inputName = "Smith"

// will NOT append "Jack"
if names.contains(inputName) {
    // name is already exist
} else {
    names.append(inputName)
}
```

---

**Tip:**

If `makeTheTeam` function should receive an unspecific number of strings, I would suggest to declare it as *variadic*:

```
func makeTheTeam(listOfName: String...) { // ...
```

Comment: I don't know if variadic is the way to go here.  Depending on how the list of names is generated, it might be hard to call the function with it.